# Unable to retrieve records from azure storage table when manually inserting records

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am having problem retrieving records from azure storage table when the record is inserted from the portal itself. The table structure is fairly simple:

```
package com.nielsen.batchJobsManager.storage.entities;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity;

public class BatchJobConfigEntity extends TableServiceEntity {

    public BatchJobConfigEntity(String jobPrefix, String configName) {
        this.partitionKey = jobPrefix;
        this.rowKey = configName;
    }

    public BatchJobConfigEntity() {
    }

    public String configValue;

    public void setConfigValue(String configValue) {
        this.configValue = configValue;
    }

    public String getConfigValue() {
        return this.configValue;
    }
}
```

I am just trying to fetch the configValue stored in the table but I am having no luck, as you can see from the screen shot. However I have noticed that if I add the record using java application "TableOperation.insertOrMerge" then it works but I just do not understand why it should matter!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution just trying random stuff! I hope this will come handy for folks who are facing the same issue. So turns out the propertyName must follow camel case but with first character capitalized. So :

[image]

had to be changed to :

[image]

Only after inserting like that I was able to get the configValue from table entity object correctly.

Comment: `So turns out the propertyName must follow camel case but with first character capitalized` - Not true. `configValue` is a valid attribute name.

Comment: I never said it's invalid, it's only when you insert data via portal it seems like you have to have the attribute name typed in certain case order. Try it out.